# Using gdal_proximity inside conda environment

Tags: python, gdal, conda

I want to batch [gdal_proximity](https://svn.osgeo.org/gdal/trunk/gdal/swig/python/scripts/gdal_proximity.py) using python.

The following command is working inside OSGeo4W Shell:

```
C:\python ./gdal_proximity.py -srcband 1 -distunits PIXEL -values 1 -ot Float32 -of GTiff "[INPUT LAYER PATH]" "[OUTPUT PATH]"
```

But I get an error when using following script inside conda environment:

```py
import gdal
import subprocess
subprocess.run(['python', './gdal_proximity.py', '-srcband', '1', '-distunits', 
                'PIXEL', '-values', '1', '-ot', 'Float32', '-of', 'GTiff',
                '"[INPUT LAYER PATH]"', '"[OUTPUT PATH]"'])
```

The error:

```
ERROR 4: `"[INPUT LAYER PATH]"' does not exist in the file system, 
and is not recognized as a supported dataset name.
Unable to open "[INPUT LAYER PATH]"
```

Comment: "C:/Users/Mann/Desktop/300m_1995_lu.tif"

Comment: Did you install `gdal` in conda using `conda install gdal`?

Comment: @Aaron Yes, It's installed. As I showed in code snippet, I even imported it.

Comment: How specifically did you install `gdal`? What command did you use?

Comment: Change `'"[INPUT LAYER PATH]"'` to `'[INPUT LAYER PATH]'`. The python subprocess will handle command line quoting for you.